# CodeIgniter application on Amazon EC2 displays blank pages

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I have my CodeIgniter application running on an Amazon instance. I have created the required databases too (On MySQL).

I used to get **blank pages** when I tried to access it using the amazon elastic IP/Appname.

I checked my index.php thinking it was not loading the controllers. But in the `index` function of my default controller, I did a simple `echo "Hello!";` and this turns up just fine!

But I actually load my db in the index function and do a lot of queries through the model.

Hence the problem must be with the DB. Though I cannot put my finger on it.
How do I get rid of these blank pages??

Any help??

Thanks in advance..

PS: The same application worked on localhost without any other changes.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Oh! Sorry! The questions are, how do I make sure that the DB is connected? And how do I get rid of these abominable blank pages??

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been solved.

First of all, I re-installed MySQL with PHP (`sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql`)

And then I had to change the login settings of the MySQL on the database.php. :)